# no valid OpenPGP data found while installing Google bazel

Tags: apt, 16.10, curl, openpgp

I am trying to install Google Bazel in Ubuntu 16 following instructions given [here](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install.html#compiling-from-source). I have `jdk1.9` installed. When I try to run `$ curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -` in the terminal, i get an error saying

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bazel.build
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`
```

How should I resolve this??

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by adding the following commands in the ubuntu server:

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

then add the line on the bottom line

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`